# Unable to create AAD app under azure media services. ( Service principal authentication )

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I am new to azure & azure media services. I started creating sample by following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/stream-files-tutorial-with-api.

I have created media service & storage service. Now but when I reach to "API access" section. I am keep getting following error even I am top level admin role.

[image] & the link is not that much helpful or guide what i need to do.

That would be great help if anyone can guide me what i am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This normally would indicate that you do not have the correct permissions in your Azure Subscription to create a Azure AD application.  You can confirm this by first going into the Subscription section of the portal and seeing what role you are in.  You can also confirm this by going directly into Azure AD and trying to create an Application in that page of the portal (or use the CLI as well.)  If you are getting the same error message there, it is likely that you have not been granted permission to create Azure AD applications in your primary tenant.   You can contact your subscription administrator to ask them to do this for you, or add you to the permission group.

Comment: I am the one who own the azure account, so assume i m the super admin. however i am not able to create AAD app.

Comment: Recommend filing a support ticket and seeing if there is something up with the subscription.  Is it a free subscription or MSDN? It may be setup in some way that is limited.

Comment: Another thing to try is to create another new AAD tenant in your account and see if it lets you create apps in it.